# Missing some Python OCC module

Tags: python, step

I am reading STEP file ( which supports exact color of a component) by using Python and its working successfully but object showing only one color. So I am not getting any idea how to solve this issue.

Another situation here -
Downloaded pythonOCC-0.16.0-win32-py34.exe and installed. After installation found some module is missing (for example - OCC.STEPCAFControl, OCC.TDocStd). How to get this module?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This module was added to pythonocc after the 0.16 release, which is why it's not included. You'll have to rebuild the project.

Comment: Can you give some idea how to rebuild the project?